# How to send a video stream to a cloud?

Tags: sockets, azure, video-streaming, cloud

I want to send a live video stream to a server and I want to perform facial recognition on that video and I would like to get the result back to the client program. Where do I get a server? Can I use Windows Azure here? If yes, can I also make a Python/C++ Server program listen on a particular port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't talked about the client-side piece. Assuming you're in control of a client app, you could push the video to a Blob, then drop a notification in an Azure queue for a background task to process the uploaded video fragment.

Instead of directly pushing to blobs, you could host a web service that lets you push uploads, and the web service could store the video fragment and then trigger a background processing task.

Running python should be very straightforward - just upload the python exe and any related modules, either with your Windows Azure deployment or in blob storage (then pull them down from blob storage and install them when the VM starts up). As far as port-listening, you can define up to 25 ports that are external-facing. You'd then have your python app listen on the port you defined (either tcp, http, or https).

More info on block and page blobs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691964.aspx). Steve Marx posted [this example](http://things.smarx.com/#Install%20Python) for installing python in your Web or Worker role.

Comment: Yes I am in control of the client app. It will be an android application and I need to connect to the Cloud (My server app). Will that be a socket connection? I am still not clear how will I make the server app listen on a particular external-facing port? I don't want a web page, I just want the client app to connect to the server app so that I can stream my video. Can you give me a tutorial link? Everywhere I look, I find apps which are web pages and not processes. Please help.

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://www.davidmakogon.com/2011/05/windows-azure-tip-go-beyond-5-endpoints.html) about 8 months ago, showing how to configure a bunch of endpoints. This will at least let you see what the UI looks like when you configure a worker role. You really just right-click the role, go to properties, click Endpoints, and add a named endpoint, protocol (http, tcp, https), and port. That port is external-facing to the world. The load-balancer maps it to a random port, unless you choose which port to use internal to the VM as well.

Comment: Also: Check out the [Windows Azure Toolkit for Android](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-android), which lets you access storage directly from your Android app, or use a proxy, sitting in a Windows Azure role, to access storage.